# Python data structure which takes combination of <non_substring_key,value> as unique

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm, class, dictionary

Python dictionaries takes `key` as unique. But I am struggling to write(find) a DS which supports follows:

**Example 1**:

```
|------|-----------------|
| abc  | matched in abcD |
|------|-----------------|
| match| matched in abcD |
|------|-----------------|
| abc  | abc found again |
```

if next entry comes as:

```
|-----|-----------------|                     
| abcd| matched in abcD |  ----> should replace first entry because abc is substring of abcd.
```

So entries/table should look like

```
|------|-----------------|
| abcd | matched in abcD |
|------|-----------------|
| match| matched in abcD |
|------|-----------------|
| abc  | abc found again |
```

**Any suggestions ?**

possible function definition

```
def substring_value_confirm(keys, values):
    # implement as above
    return required_mapping

substring_value_confirm(["abc","match","abc","abcd"],["matched in abcD", "matched in abcD", "abc found again", "matched in abcD"])
```

for any new entry first `value` should be matched if `value` is existing then `key` will be checked if one `key` is a substring of other then longer one should get the place.

**Example 2:**

```
|------|----|
| a    | 1  |
|------|----|
| b    | 2  |
|------|----|
| ba   | 3  |
```

if new entries are

```
|------|----|
| ab   | 1  |   ----> should replace first
|------|----|
| b    | 2  |   ----> should be discarded because already present
|------|----|
| ab   | 3  |   ----> will be new insertion
```

So result entry/table should be :

```
|------|----|
| ab   | 1  |
|------|----|
| b    | 2  |
|------|----|
| ba   | 3  |
|------|----|
| ab   | 3  |
```

Comment: Any algorithmic requirements on the data structure? I guess `O(1)` "access" and "insertion" is probably impossible. Is `O(n)` sufficient?

Comment: Most optimal are always good but as of now I am interested to know approach/solution.

Comment: regarding the second `abc`, what do you meant by `abc found again`? is that a value? also any string is a substring of itself and this is a contradict to your second condition. You mean if both keys are identical you should add it to the dictionary?

Comment: for any new entry first value should be matched if value is existing then `key` checking will start if `key` satisfy substring criteria then longer one should get the place.

Comment: Can you please add a minimal and verifiable example with a valid dictionary? something like `dict([('a', 2), ('ccd', 5), ('ba', 6), ('ba', 7), ('gf', 10)])`. What's the expected output of this?

Comment: for your example output should be {'a' : 2, 'ccd': 5, 'ba' :6, 'ba': 7, 'gf': 10 } if someone like to add one more entry like ('aba', 6) then ('ba', 6) will be replaced with ('aba', 6)

Comment: what about adding `('aba', 9)` for example? and `('a', 10), ('a', 2)`? Also why it will replace `ba` and not `a` because both are substrings of it?

Comment: Please update your question with all these details and different cases.

Comment: @Kasramvd, ('aba', 9) will check if 9 is present answer is no so it will add. ('a', 10) will check if 10 is present then answer is yes then it will match corresposnding key it will find `gf` which is not/of subtring of 'a' so ('a', 10) is also ok. last one is already present entry so discarded

Comment: I think a prefix tree along with a list of tuples representing the entries would work. The prefix tree is used for checking whether a substring of this key exists in linear time (linear in the length of the key). Each node of the prefix tree could contain a list of indices which correspond to the entries with the path to that node from the root as the key. I'll write up an answer in the morning.